# How to find n average number of trials before criteria are met with differing probabilities per outcome?

Tags: math, statistics, probability, markov-chains, multinomial

I've spent a few days trying to figure this out and looking up tutorials, but everything I've found so far seems like it's close to what I need but don't give the results I need.

I have a device that produces a single letter, A-F. For simplicity's sake, you can think of it like a die with letters. It will always produce one and only one letter each time it is used. However it has one major difference: **each letter can have a differing known probability of being picked:**

```
A: 25%
B: 5%
C: 20%
D: 15%
E: 20%
F: 15%
```

These probabilities remain constant throughout all attempts.

Additionally, I have a specific combination I must accrue before I am "successful":

```
As needed: 1
Bs needed: 3
Cs needed: 0
Ds needed: 1
Es needed: 2
Fs needed: 3
```

**I need find the average number of letter picks (i.e. rolls/trials/attempts) that have to happen for this combination of letters to be accrued.** It's completely fine for any individual outcome to have more than the required number of letters, but success is only counted when each letter has been chosen at least its minimum amount of times.

I've looked at plenty of tutorials for multinomial probability distribution and similar things, but I haven't found anything that explains how to find average number of trials for a scenario like this. Please kindly explain answers clearly as I'm not a wiz with statistics.

Comment: Hi! This problem can easily be solved with a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Comment: @Stef Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Would you be kind enough provide a simple example? I've looked over the page you linked and several other tutorials but I'm having a difficult time grasping it as most formulae are solving for probability and I'm not sure how to convert that to an average number of attempts.
Also, a clarification - the probabilities for each letter remain constant throughout all attempts. I expect this should make an example much simpler.

Comment: And, of course, you could use Monte-Carlo to compute average, could give you a start how to do that

Comment: @AdamLampman Sorry, my intent was to write an answer after posting this comment, but life distracted me

Comment: @AdamLampman List all the possible states (a, b, c, d, e, f) (with 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 3, c = 0, etc. since we don't care if a > 1, etc.). Then build the transition matrix Q defined by Q(i, j) = proba of going to state j when rolling a die while in state i. There are 196 states so use a computer program. Make sure to list the states in an order so that the absorbing state (1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3) comes last and the first state (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) comes first. Then compute M = (I - Q)^-1 where I is identity matrix, and ^-1 is matrix inversion.

Comment: In this new matrix M, the entry M(i, j) is the expected number of visits of state j if you start from state i, before reaching the absorbing state. Since we start in state 0, you should sum the first row (all the M(0, j)) to get the expected number of steps to go from state 0 to the absorbing state.

Comment: @AdamLampman I'll try to find a link to a webpage that better explains all this.

Comment: @AdamLampman I posted an answer, with explanations and python code. I get result 61.28, which appears consistent with Mankind_008 's estimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to *Severin's* answer that logically looks good to me but might be costly to evaluate *(i.e. infinite sum of factorials)*.
Let me provide some intuition that should give a good approximation.

Considering each ***category*** at a time. Refer this [math stackexchange question/ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417302/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-before-k-heads). Expected number of tosses in which you would get the *k* number of successes for each category *(i)* can be calculated as *k(i)/ P(i)*:

```
Given,
p(A): 25% ; Expected number of tosses to get 1 A = 1/ 0.25 = 4
p(B): 5% ; Expected number of tosses to get 3 B's = 3/ 0.05 = 60
p(C): 20% ; Expected number of tosses to get 0 C = 0/ 0.20 = 0
p(D): 15% ; Expected number of tosses to get 1 D = 1/ 0.15 = 6.67 ~ 7
p(E): 20% ; Expected number of tosses to get 2 E's = 2/ 0.20 = 10
p(F): 15% ; Expected number of tosses to get 3 F's = 3/ 0.15 = 20
```

you get an idea that ***getting 3 B's is your bottleneck***, you can *expect on average 60 tosses* for your scenario to play out.

Comment: Yeah, thought about something like this  if do Monte-Carlo. Looks right, have a bump.

Comment: Thanks, yeah multinomial distribution based simulation should provide similar results.

Comment: @Mankind_008 This is very similar to what I sussed out on my own, with the exception that I also accounted for "miss" throws when the zero letter(s) (in this case, C) are chosen by multiplying the bottleneck letter by 1 + Sum_of_zero_letter_probabilities. 

`Max_Toss_Letter_Count * (1 + Sum_of_all_zero_letter_probabilities)`
So in this case, my model would be:

`Tosses(B) * (1 + p(C)) = 60 * (1 + 0.2) = 72`
I did this since all zero-letter hits essentially count against all other letters. This feels like a good approximation but I'm not sure how solid of a model it is.

Comment: @AdamLampman you don't need to correct for C. It will occur on an average 20% of your tosses, but will not affect your definition of success. If you are not able to wrap your head around it, you can simulate it to get the same result. I can post a simulation of the scenario in python if you want

Comment: Awesome and simple answer! I calculated the exact expected number of rolls to be 61.28 using a Markov chain. This appears to be in accordance with your estimation.

Comment: I have to agree with this assessment. I wrote a quick C++ simulation that got the average number of draws from 1,000,000 trials and the average was 61.5468 draws per trial. Apparently I was overthinking this. I'm going to mark @Mankind_008 's response as the answer since it's the simplest reasonably accurate answer that can be rapidly computed. Thanks to everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Well, minimum number of throws is 10. Average would be infinite sum

A=10•P(done in 10)+11•P(done in 11)+12•P(done in 12) + ...

For P(done in 10) we could use multinomial

P(10)=Pm(1,3,0,1,2,3|probs), where probs=[.25, .05, .20, .15, .20, .15]

For P(11) you have one more throw which you could distribute like this

P(11)=Pm(2,3,0,1,2,3|probs)+Pm(1,4,0,1,2,3|probs)+Pm(1,3,0,2,2,3|probs)+
Pm(1,3,0,1,3,3|probs)+Pm(1,3,0,1,2,4|probs)

For P(12) you have to distribute 2 more throws. Note, that there are combinations of throws which are impossible to get, like Pm(2,3,0,2,2,3|probs), because you have to stop earlier

And so on and so forth

Comment: Hi! Could you write code in some programming language, and see what result you end up with? I love it when math questions are answered with several different approaches, and we can compare that the results are consistent.

Comment: @Stef maybe latter, have time pressing issues

Comment: Am still interested :)

Comment: Hi! Two years later, any chance you could get a numerical result using the method you describe in this post?

Answer (score 0):

Your process can be described as a Markov chain with a finite number of states, and an absorbing state.

The number of steps before reaching the absorbing state is called the hitting time. The expected hitting time can be calculated easily from the transition matrix of the Markov chain.

- Enumerate all possible states (a, b, c, d, e, f). Consider only a finite number of states, because "b >= 3" is effectively the same as "b = 3", etc. The total number of states is `(1+1)*(3+1)*(0+1)*(2+1)*(3+1) = 192`.
- Make sure that in your enumeration, starting state (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) comes first, with index 0, and absorbing state (1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3) comes last.
- Build the transition matrix `P`. It's a square matrix with one row and column per state. Entry `P[i, j]` in the matrix gives the probability of going from state `i` to state `j` when rolling a die. There should be at most 6 non-zero entries per row.
- For example, if `i` is the index of state `(1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2)` and `j` the index of state `(1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2)`, then `P[i, j]` = probability of rolling face B = 0.05. Another example: if `i` is the index of state `(1,3,0,0,0,0)`, then `P[i,i]` = probability of rolling A, B or C = 0.25+0.05+0.2 = 0.5.
- Call `Q` the square matrix obtained by removing the last row and last column of `P`.
- Call `I` the identity matrix of the same dimensions as `Q`.
- Compute matrix `M = (I - Q)^-1`, where `^-1` is matrix inversion.
- In matrix `M`, the entry `M[i, j]` is the expected number of times that state `j` will be reached before the absorbing state, when starting from state `i`.
- Since our experiment starts in state 0, we're particularly interested in row 0 of matrix M.
- The sum of row 0 of matrix M is the expected total number of states reached before the absorbing state. That is exactly the answer we seek: the number of steps to reach the absorbing state.

To understand why this works, you should read a course on Markov chains! Perhaps this one: [James Norris' course notes on Markov chains](https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Markov/). The chapter about "hitting times" (which is the name for the number of steps before reaching target state) is [chapter 1.3](https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Markov/s13.pdf).

Below, an implementation in python.

```py
from itertools import product, accumulate
from operator import mul
from math import prod
import numpy as np

dice_weights = [0.25, 0.05, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 0.15]
targets = [1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]

def get_expected_n_trials(targets, dice_weights):
    states = list(product(*(range(n+1) for n in targets)))
    base = list(accumulate([n+1 for n in targets[:0:-1]], mul, initial=1))[::-1]
    lookup = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(states)))
    P = np.zeros((len(states), len(states)))
    for i, s in enumerate(states):
        a,b,c,d,e,f = s
        for f, p in enumerate(dice_weights):
            #j = index of state reached from state i when rolling face f
            j = i + base[f] * (s[f] < targets[f]) 
            j1 = lookup[s[:f] + (min(s[f]+1, targets[f]),) + s[f+1:]]
            if (j != j1):
                print(i, s, f, ' --> ' , j, j1)
            assert(j == j1)
            P[i,j] += p
    Q = P[:-1, :-1]
    I = np.identity(len(states)-1) 
    M = np.linalg.inv(I - Q)
    return M[0,:].sum()

print(get_expected_n_trials(targets, dice_weights))
# 61.28361802372382
```

Explanations of code:

- First we build the list of states using Cartesian product `itertools.product`
- For a given state `i` and die face `f`, we need to calculate `j` = state reached from i when adding f. I have two ways of calculating that, either as `j = i + base[f] * (s[f] < targets[f])` or as `j = lookup[s[:f] + (min(s[f]+1, targets[f]),) + s[f+1:]]`. Because I'm paranoid, I calculated it both ways and checked that the two ways gave the same result. But you only need one way. You can remove lines `j1 = ...` to `assert(j == j1)` if you want.
- Matrix `P` begins filled with zeroes, and we fill up to six cells per row with `P[i, j] += p` where `p` is probability of rolling face `f`.
- Then we compute matrices `Q` and `M` as I indicated above.
- We return the sum of all the cells on the first row of `M`.

To help you better understand what is going on, I encourage you to examine the values of all variables. For instance you could replace `return M[0, :].sum()` with `return states, base, lookup, P, Q, I, M` and then write `states, base, lookup, P, Q, I, M = get_expected_n_trials(targets, dice_weights)` in the python interactive shell, so that you can look at the variables individually.

Answer (score 0):

A Monte-Carlo simulation:

- Actually roll the die until we hit the requirements;
- Count how many rolls we did;
- Repeat experiment 1000 times to get the empirical average value.

Implementation in python:

```py
from collections import Counter
from random import choices
from itertools import accumulate
from statistics import mean, stdev

dice_weights = [0.25, 0.05, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 0.15]
targets = [1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]

def avg_n_trials(targets, dice_weights, n_experiments=1000):
    dice_faces = range(len(targets))
    target_state = Counter(dict(enumerate(targets)))
    cum_weights = list(accumulate(dice_weights))
    results = []
    for _ in range(n_experiments):
        state = Counter()
        while not state >= target_state:
            f = choices(dice_faces, cum_weights=cum_weights)[0]
            state[f] += 1
        results.append(state.total()) # python<3.10: sum(state.values())
    m = mean(results)
    s = stdev(results, xbar=m)
    return m, s

m, s = avg_n_trials(targets, dice_weights, n_experiments=10000)
print(m)
# 61.4044
```